# Setting JavaFX TreeView Line Style

Tags: javafx-2

In Java Swing, there is JTree.linestyle property that enables/disables lines connecting the parent nodes in a tree to their children. Is there something similar in JavaFX 2? In all of the TreeView examples I've looked at for JavaFX, I haven't seen this. I also didn't see a CSS property to set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaFX 2.2 does not have such a setting out of the box.
A feature request could be filed in the [JavaFX issue tracker](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com).

You may be able to achieve the line connection effect by creating custom `TreeCell` and `TreeItem` nodes and, on those, setting the [treeCell.disclosureNodeProperty](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeCell.html#disclosureNodeProperty) and the TreeItem [graphicProperty](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeItem.html#graphicProperty%28%29) as appropriate based upon the various settable event handlers for the TreeItem.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll punt and go back to Swing.

Comment: This question is very old. Is there any new information? @jewelsea can you show us some quick sample, please?

Comment: Issue tracker reference is [RT-27031 TreeView needs option to show connecting lines](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-27031), currently not scheduled for implementation, though patch contributions are welcome for it.  I have no code for a pure JavaFX solution.  In Java 8, you can render a Swing Tree (with lines) in JavaFX using a SwingNode.