# Changing the style of a TreeView in JavaFX with CSS

Tags: css, javafx, treeview

i'm trying to style a TreeView in JavaFX using the CSS file, but there's a thing i can't understand: 
I'd like my TreeView to appear with the lines 
[like in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mEPm.png), but i obtain them only like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmY9P.png).
Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: I am guessing you can set the graphic of each node. If a node has children, use a folder icon/image. If a node is an edge node or does not have children use a file icon/image.

Comment: The fact is that that wouldn't solve the problem, it's not needed to see folder/file icon, but to see the lines of the hierarchy, I have to display a running task with his children (like in a master-slave architecture), and it has to be extremely clear which process is slave of which master.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting JavaFX TreeView Line Style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13768483/setting-javafx-treeview-line-style)

Comment: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8090579

Comment: https://gist.github.com/james-d/3da84819033a03db1496

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * the disclosure node is a StackPane, and has as a child another StackPane with style class arrow
 */

.tree-table-row-cell > .tree-disclosure-node > .arrow,
.tree-table-row-cell:expanded > .tree-disclosure-node > .arrow{
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
.tree-table-row-cell > .tree-disclosure-node{
    -fx-background-image: url("/icons/icons8_stop_sign_100px_1.png"); /* Url of the icon */
    -fx-background-size: 90% 90%; /* Can be `cover` or `100% 100%` ect. */
    -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -fx-background-position: center center; /* Put the icon in the center */
}
.tree-table-row-cell:expanded > .tree-disclosure-node {
    -fx-background-image: url("/icons/icons8_new_moon_100px_1.png"); /* Url of the icon */
    -fx-background-size: 90% 90%; /* Can be `cover` or `100% 100%` ect. */
    -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -fx-background-position: center center; /* Put the icon in the center */
}
```